# jquery.corner.js rounded corner in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounded-corners

I am trying to use an image with jquery.corner.js it works fine if I use it with background-color but I dont get rounded corners(in FF and IE) if used with background-image.

```
<div style="background-image:url('images/btn_middle.png'); padding:10px;" class="rounded">

Some content 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their site says it doesn't work with images.
you could use CSS:

```
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

which will work in all but IE.  For IE you could use CSS behaviors. [Round Corders HTC](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/)

Comment: I prefer [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/) instead of Round Corders HTC. Because Background images didn't worked for rounded corner elements.